# Directory.GetFiles returns no files... sometimes

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, .net-3.5, timer-jobs

I'm trying to get a file from a network share during a SharePoint job execution. Funny thing is that this works flawlessly on my Dev machine and it works as well as a Console Application on Production, but I can't get any files during job execution on Prod using the same network path and account information.

This is the simple piece of code:

```
var filePath = @"Z:\";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "?.gpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
if (files.Length == 0) return null
```

I'm on SharePoint 2010 so I cannot try anything else that .NET3.5.
I'm going crazy. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,

```
    public DBStoreDocument(string filePath)
    {
        this.Load(filePath);
    }



string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"" + directory, "*.gpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
     Documenttest doc = new Documenttest(path);

}
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to be a complete example